# why am i getting this error when reading a .json file?

Tags: python, json, file-handling

so i have this function to read a json file and return a dictionary of the data inside the file passed through it

```
def file_read(source):
    with open(source) as file:
        data = file.read()
        dictionary = json.loads(data)
        return dictionary
```

the file i am using it called 'users.json' and formatted

```
{"Jim":("password", "MMA60V")}
```

however whenever i try and run the code to read whats in 'users.json' i get this error

````
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 8 (char 7)```

does anyone know why this is happening and a possible solution thank you.
````

Comment: Try: `{"Jim":["password", "MMA60V"]}`

The JSON format uses square brackets `[ ]` for arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not correct JSON and since you are using `json.loads`, you get an error.

Paste the JSON into https://jsonlint.com/ and you can see that input is invalid. JSON doesn't have support for a tuple.

Comment: that worked thank you i will mark it as the answer when i can